# permuting columns of a matrix with replacement and clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

How can I permute the columns of a matrix with replacement in R? I found one function called rmperm {sna} but it permutes both columns and rows whereas I just want to permute my columns.

Edit:
I have to permute the matrix 1000 times and then do hierarchical clustering so I have the final tree after 1000 randomizations.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `sample()` function.

```
> m <- matrix(as.integer(runif(9,0,9)),ncol=3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    0    5
[2,]    6    0    0
[3,]    2    1    3
> permuted <- m[,sample(ncol(m), 10, replace=TRUE)]
> permuted
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    5    0    5    5    5    5    0    5    5     5
[2,]    0    0    0    0    6    0    0    0    6     0
[3,]    3    1    3    3    2    3    1    3    2     3
```

The first argument to `sample()` specifies the range of the sample (`1:x`), the second argument specifies the number of items to choose (`size`), and the `replace` parameter specifies whether or not we want to use replacement (required if size > x).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to permute the matrix 1000 times and then do hierarchical clustering so I have the final tree after 1000 randomizations. This permutes my matrix perfectly but if I put a loop and do permutation in it and then within the loop the clustering. Should I plot the clustering results outside of the loop? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. You'd probably want to define some variable before the loop in which you'll store your results and then merge/plot them after the loop is complete.

Comment: This is where I am lost. I have this loop 'for(i in 1:1000)
{
permuted <- test2_matrix[,sample(ncol(test2_matrix), 12, replace=TRUE)]
d = dist(permuted, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)
clust = hclust(d, method = "complete", members=NULL)
}
png (filename="cluster_dendrogram_bootstrap.png", width=1024, height=1024, pointsize=10)
plot(clust)'

Comment: Really tough to read in that format. You'll probably be better off posting a new question for that issue.